# What is the difference in meaning between two sentences?

Tags: meaning

What is the difference in meaning between two sentences?

1 ) Voltage plays a similar role on the electric system ensuring the stability of power flows.

2 ) Voltage plays a similar role on the electric system **in** ensuring the stability of power flows.

Does 1) sentence mean "Voltage plays a similar role on the electric system and the electirc system is ensuring the stability of power flows.(Voltage plays a similar role on the electric system that is ensuring the stability of power flows.) ?

Does 2) sentence mean "Voltage plays a similar role on the electric system, because Voltage is ensuring the stability of power flows.(Voltage plays a similar role on the electric system in that voltage is ensuring the stability of power flows.) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the first sentence would mean that voltage **ensures** the stability of the power flows.

The second sentence means that voltage plays a role, but doesn't necessarily ensure the stability entirely.

So basically the first sentence says that it is **responsible entirely** (or almost entirely) for maintaining stability, but the second sentence says that it just has a role in it, but is not soley responsible.